# Deleting data from a database - how to?

Tags: android, database

I want to delete specific row in database which I inserted. I can know specific row by id I put it

this is the insert method

```
 public void addButtonClicked(View view){

            String naStr = etName.getText().toString();
            String phStr = etPhone.getText().toString();

            if(naStr.isEmpty() || phStr.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please, fill-in missing data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }


            db.execSQL("insert into "+ dbHandler.TABLE_NAME + "(" + dbHandler.COLUMN_NAME + ","+ dbHandler.COLUMN_PHONE +") VALUES (?,?)", new String[] {naStr,phStr});

            String tstMsg;
            tstMsg = "Name: " + naStr + ", Phone: " + phStr +  " is inserted";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tstMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            etName.setText("");
            etPhone.setText("");


        }
I want to delete specific by id 
 public void delTsk(View view){

        String id =  etID.getText().toString();

        if(id.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please, fill-in missing data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```

can you give me any idea how to delete or something I can learn from it?

Comment: Is your `addButtonClicked()` method working? ie. is it actually inserting the data into the database? I highly recommend you learn the [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) as it has some good api for database related functionalities.

Comment: yes its work but I can not delete specific record i know id but when I delete I can not try  db.execSQL("DELETE FROM dbHandler WHERE TABLE_ID='"+etID+"'"); but it can not work

Comment: yes I add id and I specific id for each record but I just have problem in delete them

Answer (score 1):

So when using a data base you have add a primary-id for every table .
If you are doing that then you need to check the Id that is entered along with data then you can use this query to delete the data from db .

`db.execSQL("delete from + dbHandler.TABLE_NAME +  where id='your_colum_id'")`

Comment: I try this code         db.execSQL("delete from  dbHandler.TABLE_NAME   where etID = id;");
 but I cannot delete

Comment: remove the ; at the end  of id ` where etID = id;` .

Comment: i personally would recommend you to use Room for Database 

https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942 

follow this tutorial link

Comment: delete query -> db.execSQL("delete from "+ dbHandler.TABLE_NAME +"  where etID ='"+yourId+"'") and what error it throwing?